# In tableau, I want to create a calculated field which is based on a filter and outputs an answer also based on a filter

Tags: tableau-api

I created a calculated field based on a parameter with [param1, param2, param3], and I want it to output the number of entries based on another filter [fil1, fil2, fil3].

Should look like something like this...I'm not sure if tableau can do it and if it can, how?

```
IF [parameter] = 'param1'
THEN [#Entries] WHERE [filter] = 'fil1', 'fil2', and 'fil3' //total entries
ELSEIF [parameter] = 'param2'
THEN [#Entries] WHERE [filter] = 'fil2' //entries based on fil2
ELSEif [parameter] = 'param3'
THEN [#Entries] WHERE [filter] = 'fil3' //entries based on fil3
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but should work like that????

EDIT: It's actually COVID19 data.

My parameters: Total Cases, Recoveries, and Deaths.

My filter is based on Health Status: Active, Recovered, and Died.

Based on a button, I want to choose 'Total Cases' and my graph of # of cases vs date will show all active, recovered, dead cases. If I choose 'Recoveries', the graph will only show recovered, and if I choose 'Deaths'. it will show deaths data.

Comment: If you can explain it with example/sample, it would have helped me in understanding it.

Comment: It's actually COVID19 data. 

My parameters: Total Cases, Recoveries, and Deaths..
My filter is based on Health Status: Active, Recovered, and Died..

Based on a button, I want to choose Total Cases and my graph of # of cases vs date will show all active, recovered, dead cases. If I choose Recoveries, the graph will only show recovered, and so on.

Comment: Added another answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your situation I feel that you need to create only one parameter and one related calculated field.

Create parameter1 for taking inputs say 1, 2, and 3.

create calculated field like this

```
CASE [parameter1]
WHEN 1 then SUM([field1 related with value 1 in parameter])
when 2 then SUM([field2 related with value 2 in parameter])
when 3 then SUM([field3 related with value 3 in parameter])
END
```

Just add this calculated field in view and control your results from '`show parameter` option.

I have done it sample `world indicators` data in tableau..  Still if you are having problems, do tell me.

[image: result]

Screenshot of parameter created for your help.

[image: parameter]

Comment: the formula I have added in calculated field is `CASE [Parameter 1]
WHEN 1 THEN sum([Birth Rate])
WHEN 2 then sum([Population 65+])
END`

Comment: I understood why you would think this, I should've specified my data set. Each row (simplified) consists of a Case ID, Date, and Health Status. So, I would be summing up strings of Case IDs. However! This really helped me think of a solution. Instead, I created new fields which sets value to 1 when it relates to a specific param. Summing up all these ones then gets me the number of cases! :D Thanks!

Comment: OK. now i got it.  In that case you can work like calculating field as `case [parameter 1] when 1 then sum(IF [Health status] = 'Recovered' then 1 end) when 2 then sum(If [Health Status] = 'Died' then 1 end) when 2 then count[Health Status] end` and set your parameter value 1 to recovered 2 to death cases and 3 to all cases.  This way single parameter will work.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you! It was like placing my new fields into just one calculating field.

Comment: Yes, added another answer on sample data.

Comment: Am glad that this worked!  @Rica though not compulsory, upvotes on preferred answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample of data as you've told.
[image]

Create a parameter as shown in following screenshot
[image]

Create a calculated field as shown in screenshot below.
[image]

Add this calc field in view and get your desired output- like this

[image]

Comment: Yup! It's like the way I made mine but waaaaay more efficient since this uses only one calculation field. Thank you! I forgot to reply yesterday that it worked